# POSIX pthread using same thread multiple times

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I'm currently dealing with, what I belive, is a fairly simple problem, which I can't seem to solve.

I have two threads in my program. The threads are running just fine, but it's the reuse of of one the threads, that are causing the problem. The following in pseudocode:

```
main() {

create thread 1;
create thread 2;

join thread 1;

}

thread 1 {
  while true
    if(some condition)
      join thread 2 
      // Use the returned value from thread 2

}

thread 2 {
  while true
    if(some condition)
      // do something
      exit thread 2(with some return value to thread 1).
}
```

So when some condition is met in thread 1, i want it to termine thread 2 untill it's done, which works just fine. The thread 2 reaches is condition and exits the thread. However, when I'm back in the while loop of thread 1, and once again reaches the condition, I want it to rerun thread 2 again. That is what is causing the problem. After executing thread 2 once, thread 1 ignores my join statement, and just polls in the while loop, being the only thread running.

So my question is. How can i reuse the join thread 2 attribute, so the program is running continuously?

Comment: Do you want to *re-start* tread 2, or do you want to reuse its return? If the latter then just save it, and don't call `join`. If the former, then reset the condition and restart the thread.

Comment: It's the former. The thread 2 changes a variable, that is shared between both threads. I want to reuse thread 2, so the variable has the correct statement, for the thread 1 to use. So the question is, how do I restart he thread?

Answer (score 0):

> After executing thread 2 once, thread 1 ignores my join statement, and just polls in the while loop, 
>   being the only thread running.

Note that in your case, pthread_join() will most likely fail with an error the 2. time. Check its return value.

However, since your thread 2 has exited, there is no thread to wait for.
You must start thread 2 again.
That is:

```
thread 1 {
  while true
    if(some condition)
      join thread 2 
      // Use the returned value from thread 2
      create thread 2;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that but, however, it causes my program to crash.

Should the 2nd create method be any different from the main create method?

Comment: @HansPeterson If it crashes, then you might want to run in a debugger to help you figure out why it crashes. It might be there's some state that you forget to reset?

Comment: Thanks :) Got it working now. I had to recreate the variable that i handed to the pthread_create method. Probably a null pointer that caused the crash.